# How to improve edge detection with pre-defined patterns in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I've written a code with MATLAB that after smoothing (with median filter for noise reduction), edge detecting with Sobel algorithm and finally thresholding, uses pre-defined patterns to omit unreal(or undesired) edges. My question is that when I apply for example `Pattern = [1 1 1;0 0 0;0 0 0]` to a edge detected (BW) image, surprisingly I have vertical edges remaining (actually no significant changes were made).

My pattern application code :

```
[l,k] = size(edgeDetected_BW);

P(1:l , 1:k)=1; //improved edge detected image
Pattern = [1 1 1;0 0 0;0 0 0];


for i=1:l-2
   for j=1:k-2
       if((edgeDetected_BW([i i+1 i+2] , [j j+1 j+2])| Pattern) == Pattern)
          P(i+1 , j+1) = 0;
       end
   end
end
```

After running this code lines were thickened and  a few dots were removed. Where is my mistake?

[image: .:Back view of a car:.]
                  .:Back view of a car:.

Dots in yellow circles is undesired.